# Max Limit of Jobs that can be chained in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

What is the maximum limit of jobs that can be chained up, in MapReduce job chaining, using `JobControl` and `ControlledJob` objects?

Comment: If this is a concern, that sounds like you've not attempted it for the number of jobs you're expecting... Worth pointing out : Spark probably will handle your data better

Comment: I was attempting for five jobs. For the first four job output was written to the repository but for the last job, output repository was just empty. The job also generated some heap memory exception. That's all happened when job was executing in local mode. When I run it in distributed mode, result came as expected without any exception. Nevertheless I haven't figured out the max limit of job, that can be chained, yet.